# Undefined property AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, properties, undefined

```
package{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class Main extends MovieClip{

    public var ability1,ability3:Ability;

    public function Main(){

        var ability1 = new Ability(30,30,"Ability Name","...",5,false);
        addChild(ability1);         
        var ability2 = new Ability(60,30,"Ability Name2","...",3,false);
        addChild(ability2);
        var ability3 = new Ability(45,60,"Ability Name3","...",5,true);
        addChild(ability3);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Check);    

        trace(ability1.Points); //outputs the value

    }
    public function Check(event:MouseEvent):void{

        trace(ability1.Points); //outputs error

    }
}}
```

Second trace gives this error:"TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties. at Main/Check()" Can you point me out at least?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the `var` statement in your `Main` method, you're assigning the instances to local variables which are only scoped within that method. Update your code as follows and you should get the results you expect:

```
package{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Main extends MovieClip{

        public var ability1:Ability;
        public var ability3:Ability;

        public function Main(){

            // I'm a local property scoped only to this method
            var ability2 = new Ability(60,30,"Ability Name2","...",3,false);
            addChild(ability2);

            // We're instance properties and can be accessed from any method 
            // in the class (and from outside the class as well)
            ability1 = new Ability(30,30,"Ability Name","...",5,false);
            addChild(ability1);  

            ability3 = new Ability(45,60,"Ability Name3","...",5,true);
            addChild(ability3);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Check);    

            trace(ability1.Points); //outputs the value

        }
        public function Check(event:MouseEvent):void{

            trace(ability1.Points); //outputs the value
            trace(ability3.Points); //outputs the other value
        }
    }
}
```